# How to set ip for vm from outside

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine

I need to set ip from outside of virtual machine.
Now we use dhcp server to bind static ip with their MAC.
But when the number of vms is larger and large, that's not easy for administer.
I want to make one interface for the clients to set the ip of the vm when creating it.

By now, i know i can mount the vm disk and config the network setting before creating the vm.
there is one problem for that, the vm disk type may be various, and sometimes they may have totally different partition structure, and may be including LVM,etc. Besides this, i don't know whether it is possible to config ip for Windows operating system with this method.

I don't know how they do this, i mean those Virtual-machine product, like Vmware.

Edit:If those virtual-machine product don't give one interface for client to set ip for vm, then how they manage their ips. we have many many vms, and we specify ip for each of them, the client just use it, they are not authorized to set their ip from within the os, though set, it won't make any sense, they will can't connect to the internet.
     I think there must be one approach for this. 
Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: As you said before the standard way is to manage it via a dhcp server. Just think of it how you would manage static ip addresses for normal, non virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all VMWare does not provide a way to set the IP for the host from it's interface. At least not a general way. If you really want to modify the guest filesystem have a look at [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) which provides tools and an api to modify guest images.

You may also want to have a look at [foreman smart proxy](http://theforeman.org/projects/smart-proxy/wiki) to manage/control your dhcp server via a REST api. If you use directly [theforeman](http://theforeman.org/) it will allow you to manage the ip addresses via a webui.